# Delay or Wait-For Statement

Tags: database, postgresql, delay, wait, sleep

I have a 500,000 line SQL script:

```sql
UPDATE users SET region_id = 9814746 WHERE id = 101 AND region_id IS null;
UPDATE users SET region_id = 9814731 WHERE id = 102 AND region_id IS null;
UPDATE users SET region_id = 3470676 WHERE id = 103 AND region_id IS null;
```

I want to INSERT a delay of `10` seconds every `50` lines. Does `pgsql` have a `waitfor` statement like `t-sql`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

> *Does pgsql have a waitfor statement like t-sql.*

Yes, [pg_sleep](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY):

```
pg=> SELECT pg_sleep(10);
 pg_sleep 
----------

(1 row)
```

Comment: If for some reason you want to run this statement as part of single select statement, you can use `select data.id from (select id, pg_sleep(10) from sometable) AS data;`

Answer (score 35):

You could call the `pg_sleep` function with the `PERFORM` statement since we don't care about returning values:

```
PERFORM pg_sleep(10);
```

Comment: @dannymo This should work: `DO $$ BEGIN PERFORM pg_sleep(1); END $$;`

Comment: what specifically `perform` does?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pg_sleep()` and `pg_sleep_for()` to delay 10 seconds as shown below according to [Delaying Execution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY):

```sql
SELECT pg_sleep(10);
```

```sql
SELECT pg_sleep_for('10 seconds');
```

```sql
SELECT pg_sleep_for('10 second');
```

In addition, you can use `pg_sleep_until()` to delay until some time as shown below:

```sql
SELECT pg_sleep_until('today 21:45');
```

```sql
SELECT pg_sleep_until('tomorrow 03:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge.

You could do something in the shell, piping your SQL through a simple script and then into PostgreSQL. E.g. with Perl:

```
cat regionupdates.sql | perl -e '$i = 1; while(<STDIN>) { $i++; print $_; if ($i % 50 == 0) { sleep 10; } }' | psql -d MYDB -L output.txt
```

BTW: I see you asked a very similar question before. It would be nice if you could accept the answers you found solved your problem:

[Begin...commit every 50 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307735/begin-commit-every-50-rows)

Comment: I included the cat as the source of the SQL may quite easily not be a file, but be generated by another program or shell script, so the structure of the command could easily be altered.

But I take your point in general.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why you got the downvote -- stylistic uses of cat aside. ;-)  If I had an upvote for every time I filtered SQL statements through perl/awk/you-name-it to get the behavior I wanted, I'd be Jon Skeet.  +1

Answer (score 0):

As pilcrow says that is the easiest way. If you do not want to see the results back, just turn off display before running pg_sleep like this -->

```
\pset tuples_only on
select pg_sleep(10) ;
\pset tuples_only off
```