# How to make a slow sql query for testing with Active Record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I would like to test a timeout handler for sql query longer than 5 seconds:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class PostgreSQLAdapter

      def configure_connection_with_statement_timeout
        configure_connection_without_statement_timeout
        ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence do
          execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000')
        end
      end
      alias_method_chain :configure_connection, :statement_timeout

    end
  end
end
```

But I don't know how to make such a slow sql query with Active Record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: [Delay or Wait-For Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331409/delay-or-waitfor-statement)

---

[pg_sleep](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY) seems to do that (10 seconds sleep):

```
SELECT pg_sleep(10);
```

See also: http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/11/how-to-make-postgresql-query-slow.html